# Reproducing arithmetic with pytorch's quantized tensors with numpy operations

Tags: numpy, pytorch, quantization

I would like to know what exact arithmetic operations I have to do to reproduce results of quantized operations in pytorch.

This is almost duplicate question to:
[I want to use Numpy to simulate the inference process of a quantized MobileNet V2 network, but the outcome is different with pytorch realized one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904210/i-want-to-use-numpy-to-simulate-the-inference-process-of-a-quantized-mobilenet-v/70650181#70650181)

But I would even simplify it with the example of adding two quantized tensors.
For example for addition of two quantized tensors in Resnet architecture I use nn.quantized.FloatFunctional().

```
self.skip_add = nn.quantized.FloatFunctional()
```

And during inference I can add two tensors via

```
out1 = self.skip_add.add(x1, x2)
```

where x1 and x2 are tensors of torch.Tensor type, quantized with fbgemm backend during post training quantization procedure.

I expected `out2_int = x1.int_repr() + x2.int_repr()` should be the same as `out1.int_repr()` (with probably need of clamping in the needed range).
However that is not the case.
Below I dump the example outputs.

So I wonder how can I  get out1 with integer operations?

```
>print(x1)
```

> ```
>       ...,
>       [-0.0596, -0.0496, -0.1390,  ..., -0.0596, -0.0695, -0.0099],
>       [-0.0893,  0.0000, -0.0695,  ...,  0.0596, -0.0893, -0.0298],
>       [-0.1092,  0.0099,  0.0000,  ..., -0.0397, -0.0794, -0.0199]]]],
>    size=(1, 256, 14, 14), dtype=torch.quint8,
>    quantization_scheme=torch.per_tensor_affine, scale=0.009925744496285915,
>    zero_point=75)
> ```

```
print(x2)
```

> ```
>       ...,
>       [ 0.1390, -0.1669, -0.0278,  ..., -0.2225, -0.0556, -0.1112],
>       [ 0.0000, -0.1669, -0.0556,  ...,  0.0556,  0.1112, -0.2781],
>       [ 0.1390,  0.1669,  0.0278,  ...,  0.2225,  0.4171,  0.0834]]]],
>    size=(1, 256, 14, 14), dtype=torch.quint8,
>    quantization_scheme=torch.per_tensor_affine, scale=0.02780967578291893,
>    zero_point=61)
> ```

```
print(x1.int_repr())
```

> ```
>       ...,
>       [69, 70, 61,  ..., 69, 68, 74],
>       [66, 75, 68,  ..., 81, 66, 72],
>       [64, 76, 75,  ..., 71, 67, 73]]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
> ```

```
print(x2.int_repr())
```

> ```
>       ...,
>       [66, 55, 60,  ..., 53, 59, 57],
>       [61, 55, 59,  ..., 63, 65, 51],
>       [66, 67, 62,  ..., 69, 76, 64]]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
> ```

print(out1)

> ```
>       ...,
>       [ 0.0904, -0.2109, -0.1808,  ..., -0.2712, -0.1205, -0.1205],
>       [-0.0904, -0.1808, -0.1205,  ...,  0.1205,  0.0301, -0.3013],
>       [ 0.0301,  0.1808,  0.0301,  ...,  0.1808,  0.3314,  0.0603]]]],
>    size=(1, 256, 14, 14), dtype=torch.quint8,
>    quantization_scheme=torch.per_tensor_affine, scale=0.03012925386428833,
>    zero_point=56)
> ```

```
print(out1.int_repr())
```

> ```
>       ...,
>       [59, 49, 50,  ..., 47, 52, 52],
>       [53, 50, 52,  ..., 60, 57, 46],
>       [57, 62, 57,  ..., 62, 67, 58]]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
> ```

```
 print(out2_int)
```

> ```
>       [135, 125, 121,  ..., 122, 127, 131],
>       [127, 130, 127,  ..., 144, 131, 123],
>       [130, 143, 137,  ..., 140, 143, 137]]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
> ```

Comment: I have found. That nn.quantized.FloatFunctional().add() is the more difficult to understand than convoulitonal layer and fully connected layer (in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904210/i-want-to-use-numpy-to-simulate-the-inference-process-of-a-quantized-mobilenet-v/70692830#70692830 I provided code that worked for me). But still cannot resolve the adding function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is twofold:

1. Integer operations are implemented taking into account that int8 number refer to different domain. Convolution (or matrix-matrix multiplication in general) is implemented with respect to this fact and my answer here [I want to use Numpy to simulate the inference process of a quantized MobileNet V2 network, but the outcome is different with pytorch realized one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904210/i-want-to-use-numpy-to-simulate-the-inference-process-of-a-quantized-mobilenet-v/70650181#70650181) worked for me.
2. Addition in pytorch is implemented in floats. You need to convert from int to float, make an addition and then convert back to int.

> ```
> def manual_addition(xq1_int, scale1, zp1, xq2_int, scale2, zp2,
> scale_r, zp_r):
>
>   xdq = scale1 * (xq1_int.astype(np.float) - zp1)
>   ydq = scale2 * (xq2_int.astype(np.float) - zp2)
>   zdq = xdq + ydq
>   zq_manual_int = (((zdq / scale_r).round()) + zp_r).round() 
>   return zq_manual_int #clipping might be needed
> ```